# How to add template reference Variable inside iframe of (button) element in angular 10.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, iframe

I need to add a template reference variable inside a dynamic generated Iframe of Button element.
Like this: <button #submitBtn> Submit

```
 ngAfterViewInit()  {    
    $('iframe').attr('id', 'IframeId');
}
 
// fire this function when main DOM Element Button of click 
onClickParentDomButton(){   
    const iframe: any = document.querySelector("#IframeId");    
    console.log('iframe.contentDocument**', iframe.contentDocument); // here is null
    const btn = iframe.contentDocument.body.querySelector("#inSideIframeBtn");      
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean here. Just realize that an iFrame is a completely different browser window instance that doesn’t just have Angular running in there..

Answer (score 0):

If the button `<button #submitBtn>` you are trying to reference is inside a iframe then you cannot reference it in the parent application using angular view child.

It seems the iframe page is also managed by you and is of same origin as the parent application. If so you can

1. Directly access element with dom query methods.

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('#myIframe');
const btn = iframe.contentDocument.body.querySelector('#submitBtn');

/// use the btn
```

2. (Preferred) Use window messaging. When the btn inside the iframe is clicked let the page emit a event with window messaging. (This would also work if the iframe content is not of same origin).

Comment: I flow this process but here btn variable value is show null

Comment: Which option of the two mentioned did you try? Please post the code so I can take a look at what the issue is.

Comment: I try option 1 and update my post by code, please review that